# Таймер в цикле Node.js

Tags: node.js

Я новичок в **Node.js** и **JavaScript** в целом. Мне нужно чтобы выполнялся цикл n кол-во раз с промежутком в секунду, и после него уже выполнялись другие команды. Я пытался использовать `setTimeout()` внутри цикла `for()`, но это не дало никаких результатов, к примеру у меня цикл выполняется 10 раз, но в таком случае у меня все 10 таймеров запускаются почти одновременно. Потом отказался от `for()` и написал на `setInterval()` с `i++` и `if(i=4) {clearInterval()}`. Дало определённые плоды, но последующие команды выполняются сразу после старта функции, а не по окончанию её.

Чтобы было более понятно приложу как должно было выглядеть в моей задумке.

```
0 секунда
1 секунда
И т.д.
Цикл окончен
```

**А как выглядит на деле:**

```
0 секунда 
Цикл окончен
1 секунда
И т.д.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам стоит разобраться, как в JS работает асинхронность: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Если вы используете последнюю версию Node.js, там есть [промисифицированные версии таймеров](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/timers.html#timers_timers_promises_api), с ними легче всё организовать:

```js
const { setTimeout } = require('timers/promises');

(async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await setTimeout(1000);
  }
})();
```

Или, если использовать ESM с поддержкой await на верхнем уровне:

```js
import { setTimeout }  from 'timers/promises';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  await setTimeout(1000);
}
```

С более старыми версиями Node.js:

```js
(async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }

  // Остальные команды...
})();
```

Comment: для nodejs версий меньше 15, можно использовать задержку в таком виде: `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));`

Comment: Таймер работает с первым вариантом vsemozhebuty без константы и строчкой nörbörnën, но подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы последующие команды выполнялись только после окончания цикла?

Comment: @АртёмВершигора Если вы используете первый вариант, последующие команды придётся вставлять внутрь асинхронной функции после цикла. Я добавил вариант для ясности.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Всё заработало, спасибо Вам огромное)

Comment: @АртёмВершигора пометьте ответ принятым, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо рекурсивно и последовательно выполнить итерацию, вы также можете применить рекурсию с асинхронным подходом, таким образом:

```js
function processRecursively(n, delay=1000, callback) {
    if (n > 0) {
        // что-то выполняем
        console.log(n);

        // рекурсивно вызываем самих себя (с нужными аргументами)
        setTimeout(processRecursively, delay, --n, delay, callback);
    } else {
        callback('done!');
    }
}

processRecursively(5, 1000, console.log);
```